# Entity Framework refresh didn't update the Table properly

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm facing issue while refreshing tables and views in Entity Framework 6 and the following are issues,

1. The removed columns in the table and I tried refreshing the EDMX, but removed columns are not properly deleted in the `.edmx` (EF)
2. Changed the column name of a table and I tried refreshing the EDMX, but column name changes are not properly updated in the `.edmx`
3. New columns are added at the bottom.. how to change the sequence?
4. When we delete a table, then all the class files created under `.tt` file are getting deleted by itself.

Please let me how to refresh the Entity Framework properly without the above issues ?

Currently, I'm deleting all the entities in the model (EDMX Diagram) and re-adding it again.

Thanks,

Prakash.

Comment: Did you try searching? Those are known issues, where the workaround (if you don't want to delete and re-add the tables) 
is to manually edit the EDMX XML.

Comment: manually editing the EDMX XML is a risky one and error prone..so currently, I'm doing it by deleting all the tables and view. and re-adding it.. but since the project is in TFS (source control). It shows all the previous entities as deleted.. and again whatever I have added shown as newly added even though many of them already present in EDMX..   To be simple, it shows lots of changes .. so, is there a way to refresh only the required tables without any issue ?

Comment: Oh yeah that's because TFS doesn't really handle that well.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to delete any table from edmx you must to remove the table name from tt file and save it again.

Comment: There are no table names in the tt file.

Comment: TableFilterExclude = new Regex("tableName$"); add this line in tt file with   the table name what you want to remove.

Comment: No,that is totally not what this question is about.

Comment: Check if the connectionstring of tt file config as same as to alter table database.

Comment: Actually, all the class files are getting deleted when I delete one table in EDMX diagram.. This is one of issue which I face while updating the EDMX.. And others I have listed above..